# EWS API - Get Teams Attendees Report for list of users?

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

So I am trying to pull Teams Attendees Reports for a list of users in the organization. Basically GotoMeeting had this feature and Microsoft has yet to give these details easily in Reporting. This script (https://dev.to/gscales/accessing-microsoft-teams-summary-records-cdr-s-for-calls-and-meetings-using-exchange-web-services-3581) works perfectly, however the problem is I can only pull the attendee reports for my own mailbox. I would like to be able to store a list of UPNs or Email Addresses in a text file; then pull the attendee report the same way, but for that list of users.

I know the script uses User Impersonation, but how do I do store a list of users so it runs the criteria on multiple users.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to store the list of data in some temporary storage or variable in your script itself?
Also, I think you will required some permissions to access the data on behalf of other users.

Comment: Yes. I have global admin rights in the tenant and I did assign myself Full Rights and Send on Behalf of rights to hand full of mailboxes.

Comment: How would I store the list in a variable based on the code of the original script. The way the script works it uses the Login of the mailbox. I believe that's the issue here is how do I isolate it to a text file. There are 2 lines in the script where it references the mailbox.  Lines 343 and 495.

Comment: Please have a look at this doc-https://powershellexplained.com/2017-03-18-Powershell-reading-and-saving-data-to-files/

Comment: How would I store the list of MailboxNames as one variable and then pass it all the way through the script?

Comment: Also, I did figure out I could pass through one user's name and I do see the script working. Would I be able to replaced with a " $_ " and just do a for-each ? Or would I have to create an individual variable for each. Not sure how I could get an array working here?

Comment: $service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "FirstName.LastName@domain.com");
            if ($useImpersonation.IsPresent) {
                $service.ImpersonatedUserId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, "FirstName.LastName@domain.com")
            }
        }
        $folderid= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Root,"FirstName.LastName@domain.com")

Comment: Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? Or even just an example of how I could store multiple users in the below function and carry it through?